# Solving matrix equation for a matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

Is there any way to define the matrix `M` that achieves the following equation?

[image]

the two defined matrices are

```
{{(ω1 + ω4) / Sqrt[2]},
 {(μ ω2 + ω3) / Sqrt[2]},
 {(-μ ω2 + ω3) / Sqrt[2]},
 {(-ω1 + ω4) / Sqrt[2]}}
```

and

```
{{ω1}, {ω2}, {ω3}, {ω4}}
```

Comment: BTW, column vectors are not a necessity.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ You're right: I realized this from the corresponding answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tt = {{(ω1 + ω4)/Sqrt[2]},
      {(μ ω2 + ω3)/Sqrt[2]},
      {(-μ ω2 + ω3)/Sqrt[2]},
      {(-ω1 + ω4)/Sqrt[2]}} // Flatten

mat =Last@ CoefficientArrays[tt, {ω1, ω2, ω3, ω4}] // Normal
```

[image: coefficient matrix]

```
mat. {ω1, ω2, ω3, ω4} - tt // Simplify
```

{0,0,0,0}

Comment: Huh. Maybe I’m mistake but is this not just putting the initial vector/set of coupled equations in a matrix form? Seems magical but I know it’s simpler than it seems. Or maybe not?

Comment: @CATrevillian yes you are right.

Answer (score 5):

`CoefficientArrays[]` works very well for this:

```
m1 = Normal[Last[CoefficientArrays[{(ω1 + ω4)/Sqrt[2], (μ ω2 + ω3)/Sqrt[2],
                                    (-μ ω2 + ω3)/Sqrt[2], (-ω1 + ω4)/Sqrt[2]},
                                   {ω1, ω2, ω3, ω4}]]]
   {{1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, μ/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0},
    {0, -(μ/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}}
```

Note how I used vectors instead of column matrices.

```
m1.{ω1, ω2, ω3, ω4} - {(ω1 + ω4)/Sqrt[2], (μ ω2 + ω3)/Sqrt[2],
                       (-μ ω2 + ω3)/Sqrt[2], (-ω1 + ω4)/Sqrt[2]}
   {0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: oops... I simplified my silly answer and I now notice its exactly the same as yours. Oh well. Don't know why the OP changed his mind about giving you the credit.